# Bluetooth Keyboard + Facebook Messenger loses focus constantly

Tags: external-keyboard, facebook-messenger

With a Galaxy Note 8, Android version 8, latest of Facebook Messenger. I am trying to use my Keyboard K780 in Messenger and the focus is lost constantly after typing one letter.

The only way I got it working is by putting focus in the textbox on Android, switch to another computer (F1), switch back to Android (F2) then the focus stays in the box.
Not quite the best experience to start typing on Android. Any clues? settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "switch to another computer"? Is this some feature of the keyboard?

Comment: @DanHulme yes it is. They keyboard can switch to another bluetooth by the press of a key, which is neat. But Messenger doesn't seem to support this bluetooth keyboard properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Settings
2. General Management
3. Language and Input
4. Physical Keyboard
5. TURN OFF -> Show on-screen keyboard
   Show the on-screen keyboard while a physical keyboard is being used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your keyboard is ON and paired.
Go to

- SETTINGS
- GENERAL MANAGEMENT
- PHYSICAL KEYBOARD K780 KEYBOARD
- Turn OFF the SHOW THE ON-SCREEN KEYBOARD option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When the text box is at the bottom of the screen press and hold in the text box until "Auto Fill" appears. You can then enter text from the keyboard.